# How to tell a macmini to stop booting to Windows from a macbook pro?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, bootcamp, mac-mini, firewire

I need to be able to control a mac mini without a screen and I think using screensharing would be enough. I've enabled screensharing, setup a manual IP address and I have an ethernet cable.

The problem is I don't have display to use on the mac mini and I currently borrowed a keyboard and a firewire cable to setup screensharing:

1. booted mac mini in target mode (wish there was a way to do it without the keyboard)
2. booted the macbook holding the `alt` key and choosing the firewire drive

The problem is the mac mini has a bootcamp partition setup to which it boots by default. I googled a bit and tried the `System Preferences > Startup Disk` option then the [/etc/fstab](https://gist.github.com/threebytesfull/968327) route but no joy: the mac mini still boots to Windows.

How can I get the macmini to simply boot to it's osx all the time (given that I have to change the settings on a macbook with a firewire cable) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system stores the boot choice in NVRAM, so you might reset it by powering off and then holding command-option-p-r while you hear the start chimes repeat 2 or 3 times.  At that point, it should choose the first bootable system on the internal drive. IF that doesn't work, you could post the filesystem layout - but a corrupt NVRAM settings file would explain why your choice of Startup Disk wasn't respected.

Comment: that worked, I could see the macmini in the network list, but still can't connect to it and not sure why. any hints on what I can check tomorrow ?

Comment: Not really, but the site should be here tomorrow for a follow up question. Just list the details and we'll have a look collectively.